# Создание нескольких inline-кнопок по нажатию. Aiogram

Tags: telegram, бот, aiogram

я хочу реализовать такие же **inline-кнопки**, как и в этом боте: https://t.me/CubeDice_Bot. Т.е при нажатии на **обыкновенную кнопку**, **создавать inline-кнопку**. Я совершил попытку это реализовать, но столкнулся с проблемой. Если два пользователя создают "комнаты", то старые "комнаты" тоже переименовываются. Я уверен, что сама моя задумка неверна, буду рад хоть каким-то мыслям!

**Основной файл**

```
    #CREATE ROOMS
global message_list #COUNTER (переделать в БД)
message_list = []

global count_list
count_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    #Костыль

async def create_rooms(message: types.Message):
    #COUNTER
    message_list.append(message.text)
    count = len(message_list)



    #CREATE INLINE BUTTONS
    if count == 1:
        but1 = await in_kb.test(message.from_user.first_name, count_list)
        await message.answer('Список комнат:\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖', reply_markup = but1[0])

    if count == 2:
        but2 = await in_kb.test(message.from_user.first_name, count_list)
        await message.answer('Список комнат:\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖', reply_markup = but2[1])

    if count == 3:
        but3 = await in_kb.test(message.from_user.first_name, count_list)
        await message.answer('Список комнат:\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖', reply_markup = but3[2])

    if count == 4:
        but4 = await in_kb.test(message.from_user.first_name, count_list)
        await message.answer('Список комнат:\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖', reply_markup = but4[3])

    if count == 5:
        but5 = await in_kb.test(message.from_user.first_name, count_list)
        await message.answer('Список комнат:\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖', reply_markup = but5[4])

    if count > 5:
        await message.answer('Больше пяти комнат создавать нельзя!')



    #CALLBACK ANSWER TO INLINE BUTTONS
    @dp.callback_query_handler(Text(contains=f'{message.from_user.first_name}&{count_list[0]}'))
    async def join_room1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
        await callback_query.answer(f'Вы вошли в комнату №{count_list[0]}', show_alert=True)

    @dp.callback_query_handler(Text(contains=f'{message.from_user.first_name}&{count_list[1]}'))
    async def join_room2(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
        await callback_query.answer(f'Вы вошли в комнату №{count_list[1]}', show_alert=True)

    @dp.callback_query_handler(Text(contains=f'{message.from_user.first_name}&{count_list[2]}'))
    async def join_room3(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
        await callback_query.answer(f'Вы вошли в комнату №{count_list[2]}', show_alert=True)

    @dp.callback_query_handler(Text(contains=f'{message.from_user.first_name}&{count_list[3]}'))
    async def join_room4(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
        await callback_query.answer(f'Вы вошли в комнату №{count_list[3]}', show_alert=True)

    @dp.callback_query_handler(Text(contains=f'{message.from_user.first_name}&{count_list[4]}'))
    async def join_room5(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
        await callback_query.answer(f'Вы вошли в комнату №{count_list[4]}', show_alert=True)


**Создание кнопки**

async def test(user_name, count_list):
    a1 = InlineKeyboardButton(f'{user_name} | комната №{count_list[0]}',\
                              callback_data = f'{user_name}&{count_list[0]}')

    a2 = InlineKeyboardButton(f'{user_name} | комната №{count_list[1]}',\
                              callback_data = f'{user_name}&{count_list[1]}')

    a3 = InlineKeyboardButton(f'{user_name} | комната №{count_list[2]}',\
                              callback_data = f'{user_name}&{count_list[2]}')

    a4 = InlineKeyboardButton(f'{user_name} | комната №{count_list[3]}',\
                              callback_data = f'{user_name}&{count_list[3]}')

    a5 = InlineKeyboardButton(f'{user_name} | комната №{count_list[4]}',\
                              callback_data = f'{user_name}&{count_list[4]}')

    room_kb1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    room_kb2 = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    room_kb3 = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    room_kb4 = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    room_kb5 = InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    room_kb1.add(a1)
    room_kb2.add(a1).add(a2)
    room_kb3.add(a1).add(a2).add(a3)
    room_kb4.add(a1).add(a2).add(a3).add(a4)
    room_kb5.add(a1).add(a2).add(a3).add(a4).add(a5)

    room_list =[room_kb1, room_kb2, room_kb3, room_kb4, room_kb5]
    return room_list
```

Answer (score 0):

**Главный файл**
В callback можно написать свою логику

```
import sqlite_db as sq
import inline_kb as in_kb

#CREATE ROOMS
async def create_rooms(message: types.Message):
    count = await sq.sql_count_rooms(message.from_user.id)
    if count[0] < 5:
        await sq.sql_counter_rooms(message.from_user.id)
        await message.answer('Комната создана ✅')
    else:
        await message.answer('Больше пяти комнат создавать нельзя!')


#PRINT LIST ROOMS
async def list_rooms(message: types.Message):
    data = await sq.sql_data()
    await message.answer('Список комнат:\n---------', reply_markup = in_kb.rooms(data))


#CALLBACK ANSWER
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
async def stoptopupcall(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id) #-Ответ.
    userinfo = await sq.sql_test(callback_query.data[:-2]) #-Ищет инфу в БД по tgid
    if userinfo:    #-если инфа есть, даёт её, если нет, то не даёт.
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, f'ID: {userinfo[0]}\nName: {userinfo[1]}\nTgid:{userinfo[2]}')
```

**Клавиатура**
Генерация клавиатуры через цикл

```
def rooms(data):
    rooms = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    rooms.row_width = 1
    for i in data:
        for count in range(1, i[3]+1):
            rooms.add(InlineKeyboardButton(f'{i[1]} | комната №{count}', callback_data=f'{i[2]}${count}'))
    return rooms
```

**Файл с БД**

```
#Choice all
async def sql_data():
    return cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Create_rooms')

#Count
async def sql_count_rooms(id):
    return cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Create_rooms WHERE tgid = ?', (id, )).fetchone()


#Counter
async def sql_counter_rooms(id):
    res = cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Create_rooms WHERE tgid == ?', (id, )).fetchone()
    print (res)
    count = res[0]
    count += 1
    cur.execute('UPDATE Create_rooms SET count = ? WHERE tgid = ?', (count, id))
    base.commit()

#test

async def sql_test(test):
    return cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Create_rooms WHERE tgid = ?', (test, )).fetchone()
```

[image: БД]